# How to rotate sphere when using Vertical Near Side Perspective projection?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, extents, arcglobe

**Situation**

Data is currently displayed on a globe using the Vertical Near Side Perspective projection with a blue circle as a backdrop.

**Problem**

I would like to 'rotate' the globe by altering the projection parameters without causing the shape files to shift away from the backdrop. The parameter that was changed was the Longitude_Of_Center

[image: Current layout]

[image: Shift in shape files]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only the longitude of center parameter is changed, the visible extents of the world are the same. I must assume that the blue background shape is a graphic shape rather than a geographic one. I have seen the data frame re-center when changing the longitude of center, which it shouldn't. If the graphic shape is defined relative to the data frame, that would cause the offset when the data frame's center changes.

My suggestion is to instead create a geographic data-based background with the [Create Fishnet Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000). Generate a 1x1 cell polygon with the origin at x/longitude = -180.0 and y/latitude = -90.0. Then set 1 row by 1 column with the row size of 180.0 and the column size equal to 360.0. Use the [Define Projection Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000077000000) to set its coordinate reference system to match the geographic CRS of your other data. Now it will project on-the-fly (in-memory) like the other layers.

Note: You could also use the Create Fishnet tool to generate a graticule data layer (latitude and longitude lines) that you can use in the data view as opposed to adding a grid/graticule in the layout view. See one of the supported map projection pages in the Map Projections Guidebook, ex. [Winkel Tripel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Winkel_Tripel/003r0000004r000000/), for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just display a blank background (water), then it is possible to:

1. Create a shapefile in the standard WGS 1984 mercator projection,
   covering the extent of the world.
2. Then change your data frame to
       your custom Vertical_Near_Side_Perspective projection, it should
       then project on-the-fly to what you want to see.

[image: Near side perspective projection with blank background]